# Gradle build failed: merge conflicts in intermediate and incremental files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I created an empty new project to figure out a gradle for all the dependencies.
I have narrowed the problems down to an error about duplicate value resources in generated code files. The error is:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:561: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_scrollFlags' with config ''.
C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:561: error: resource previously defined here.
C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:644: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/behavior_peekHeight' with config ''.
C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:644: error: resource previously defined here.
C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:678: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_collapseMode' with config ''.
C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:678: error: resource previously defined here.
C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:778: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:778: error: resource previously defined here.

Command: C:\Users\Erik\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\ec691f4c746f38f802cb8c84823b8119\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\Erik\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Erik is my username folder. I guess editing those files is not advisable, since those are generated.

I have unsuccesfully tried the following common solutions I found:

- changing the compileSDK to <26
- deleting the gradle folder
- adding android.enableAapt2=false to gradle properties
- reinstalling Android Studio

My current Android Studio version is 3.2.1, my gradle is as follows:

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    ext {
        release = [
                versionName: "3.3.0-rc01",
                versionCode: 3300
        ]

        setup = [
                compileSdk: 28 ,
                buildTools: "28.0.3",
                minSdk    : 15,
                targetSdk : 28
        ]

        versions = [
                androidX: '1.0.0',
                //supportLibrary: '27.0.0'
        ]
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    group "com.mikepenz"

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        //mpAndroid charts
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    roomVersion = '1.0.0'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
    rxJavaVersion = '2.1.7'
    fastAdapterVersion = "3.2.4"
    materializeVersion = "1.1.2"
    butterknife = '8.4.0'
}
```

App gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
//wrap with try and catch so the build is working even if the signing stuff is missing
try {
    apply from: '../../../signing.gradle'
} catch (ex) {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion setup.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion setup.buildTools

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion setup.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion setup.targetSdk
        versionCode release.versionCode
        versionName release.versionName

        multiDexEnabled true

        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "FastAdapter-v$versionName-c$versionCode")

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
            try {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            } catch (ex) {
            }
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            try {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            } catch (ex) {
            }
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            //my
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    //my
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:${versions.androidX}"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:${versions.androidX}"

    //currency
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.5'
    //serialize colls in db
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    //mpAndroid charts
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'

    // Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // view binding lib?
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'

    // used to base on some backwards compatible themes
    // contains util classes to support various android versions, and clean up code
    // comes with the awesome "Holder"-Pattern
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/Materialize
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialize:1.2.0-rc01'

    // used to provide out of the box icon font support. simplifies development,
    // and provides scalable icons. the core is very very light
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.1.0-rc01'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.1.0-rc01"

    //used to generate the drawer on the left
    //https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.0-rc01') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: "com.mikepenz"
    }
    //used to provide different itemAnimators for the RecyclerView
    //https://github.com/mikepenz/ItemAnimators
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:itemanimators:1.1.0-rc01'
    //used to generate the Open Source section
    //https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries
    implementation('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.2.0-rc01') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: "com.mikepenz"
    }
    //used to display the icons in the drawer
    //https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:1.7.22.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.1.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.0@aar'

    //Used for the StickyHeaderSample
    //https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview
    //original dependency: implementation  'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3@aar'
    //customized version to allow minimal header animation
    implementation 'com.mikepenz.thirdparty:stickyheadersrecyclerview:0.5.1-SNAPSHOT@aar'

    //Used to provide the FastScrollBar
    //https://github.com/krimin-killr21/MaterialScrollBar
    implementation 'com.turingtechnologies.materialscrollbar:lib:10.0.1'

    //https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    //used to load the images in the ImageListSample
    //https://github.com/bumptech/glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

    //Used to provide the drag selection like google photos
    implementation 'com.github.MFlisar:DragSelectRecyclerView:0.2'

    //mopub sdk to showcase the usage of the mopub adapter
    implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: "com.google.android.exoplayer"
    }

    //Used to async operations
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.mikepenz:materialize:1.2.0-rc01"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.1.0-rc01"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:6.2.0-rc01"
        resolutionStrategy.force "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${versions.androidX}"
        resolutionStrategy.force "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:${versions.androidX}"
        resolutionStrategy.force "androidx.cardview:cardview:${versions.androidX}"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.material:material:${versions.androidX}"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1"
    }
}
```

Gradle properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Comment: MaterialDrawer 6.1.0 or newer users androidX as such all your dependencies need androidX or you use the jetifier. If you want to use support and appcompat libs. just use v6.0.9 or older

Answer (score 0):

I solved with two steps:

1.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

must be put in gradle/project properties (file under gradle scripts).

2.
Omitting all supportlibraries and migrating fully to androidx. To do this, delete the support library dependencies from gradle, like

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.support.v4.whatever version
```

Now, a lot of elements in your classes and layout files will be red. For them, import new androidx imports and forget about the old v7 and v4 stuff. Beware of the AndroidX migration tool for bigger projects, it is not yet perfect. Thanks for reading my question.